# Python discord application command not found

Tags: python, discord

I registered an application command. It shows up in the discord server as so.

[Registered App Command Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4saam.png)

I try to set up the command like this. Note: I have also tried `@bot.command(name='huncho')`

```
from auth import Auth 
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot('/', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.command()
async def huncho(ctx, *f):
    print('hello')
    

if __name__=='__main__':
    bot.run(Auth.token)
```

I end up getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1219, in _call
    command, options = self._get_app_command_options(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1125, in _get_app_command_options
    raise CommandNotFound(name, parents)
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'huncho' not found
```

This code works when the command is not registered as an application command, but I'm not sure how to use a registered application command.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. There are not very many examples of this online. I hope this helps somebody. Here is what you use to register an [application command](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands) with your discord application.

The application command is found in a [CommandTree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=command%20tree#application-commands). You create a client and initialize a a command tree.

Once you initialize a CommandTree, you can create `@tree_cls.command(name='huncho')` with an `async def huncho(interaction)`. Here is a reference to the [Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction#interaction) class.
When you use this, you get the options that you initialized your application command with `interaction.data`. This is a dictionary with the values of each option and some metadata.

Here is an example:

```
from auth import Auth 
import discord 
from discord import app_commands


client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
tree_cls = app_commands.CommandTree(client)


@tree_cls.command(name='huncho')
async def huncho(interaction):
    value = 'Huncho'+' '+interaction.data['options'][0]['value']
    await interaction.response.send_message(value)
    

if __name__=='__main__':
    client.run(Auth.token)
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I have a better solution now. That is to use pycord. It will manage the creation and deletion of commands. It's also nice since it handles the intentions part. In order to use it you need to remove the old discord.py pip uninstall discord.py and install pycord pip install py-cord.